# Po command error in xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

I got this result from the debugger. How should I fix this?

> (lldb) po scrollView.contentOffset.y
>
> error: :1:1: error: ambiguous operator declarations found for
>   operator
>
> scrollView.contentOffset.y found this matching operator declarationfound this matching operator declaration:1:1: error:
>   operator is not a known binary operator scrollView.contentOffset.y ^
>   :9:9: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
>       var $__lldb_error_result = __lldb_tmp_error
>
> :14:8: error: ambiguous operator declarations found for operator
>
> if (1==1) {
>
> found this matching operator declarationfound this matching operator
>   declaration:14:8: error: operator is not a known binary operator
>
> if (1==1) {

Comment: How about `p` instead of `po`?

Comment: tried same result.

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32984193/2060180

I'll leave it here in case it's useful to someone.