# Breakpoints are not working in xcode pod files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have a xcode project which includes few cocoa pod files. When i put breakpoints in cocoa pod files, the debugger does not stops at those breakpoints, why? Could anyone have any idea about the same?.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can see if there are any issues.

Comment: I am using a third party control using pods. while debugging the code i put breakpoint in some file which is under pods projects.

Comment: Finally, i have found the solution.
1.We have set the Active build architecture settings to YES for debug.
2.Set Optimization Level to None for both Debug and release.

That's all. Thanks

Comment: this could also help, you usually get in the console "was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available." take a look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia/32892914#32892914

Comment: I had to add the framework lib to Build Phases -> Embed Pods Frameworks: 
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/mypod/libmypod_pods.a

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Project Name' was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia)

Comment: You can debug. just make 1 changes in your file which you want to debug - unlock the file.

Q - How to unlock - 
A: Just make changes in your profile like add print line etc.

Answer (score 22):

I followed @UdaySingh's comment and it worked, I'm not sure why he didn't post an answer but I realize there are people who sometimes need a step by step and a visual guide tremendously helps. Here's the visual version of his comment.

In the project navigator select the blue project icon.

[image]

**In Xcode 11.2.1 they switched the below photos to Project, it used to be under Target**

[image]

Important. The pic below is from `Project` in Xcode 11.2.1, this where you need to go:

[image]

Select `Build Settings`.

The pic below is from `Project` in Xcode 10.1, this is where you would need to go:

[image]

In the search field type `Build Active Architecture` and make sure `Debug` is set to `Yes`

[image]

In the same search field now type in `Optimization Level`.
Change `Debug` and `Release` to `None`

[image]

As per @matt’s comments below also do a clean afterwards.

That's it

Comment: You may need to do a clean build as the pod may not rebuild as expected.

Comment: Clean is mandatory, I did it without clean and it didn't work, so thanks Matt, Lance and OP.

Comment: Could you explain why optimization needs to be turned off for `Release` as well please?

Comment: I believe it's because the pods are compiled for release even though the embedding project is compiled for debug

Answer (score 9):

In my case, cleaning Pods directory and installing pods again worked.
Spent hours for this so hope it would be helpful for someone who couldn't find a solution yet.