# Debugging Cocoapods locally from another project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have two projects:

- A local cocoapod
- An app that uses the local cocoapod

The podfile of the second project (app), has the following podfile:

```
pod 'MyCustomPod', :path => 'path_to_my_cocoapod_project...'
```

When i run the app, all works fine, including when i change things on the cocoapod project (like print something). What i have to do is use breakpoint to debug the cocoapod project when running the app project. Is that possible?

I'm new on locally pod projects and didn't anything like that.

Comment: Yes absolutely!! did you try placing a break point? is it not hitting? As far as you are pulling via source code and not binary, debugging will work. if its a precompiled binary, then its not possible

Comment: @Deepika yeah, i put breakpoints in the pod project, but it's not working.

Comment: May be try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399159/breakpoints-are-not-working-in-xcode-pod-files/54655203