# Set title of UIButton that's located in a UICell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I don't understand why I can't set the title of my `UIButton`. It crashes here:

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if(section == 0) {
        let view = UIView()
        view.alpha = 0
        return kTableHeaderShouldStickToTop ? view : carouselViewController.view
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsFeedSectionHeaderCell") as! NewsFeedSectionHeaderCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.dataSource = self

        cell.followingButton.setTitle("test", forState: .Normal)
        return cell
    }
}
```

It is connected in my `.xib` file:

[image]

Comment: Have you check that it is wire up with class IBOutlet?

Comment: Yep, that was my initial response as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia

Comment: please check that which  method first call cellForRow or  viewForHeaderInSection because for what you are doing is must have cell

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether we can take cell object in **viewForHeaderInSection**: method because as per my knowledge ***viewForHeaderInSection***: is called before ***cellForRowAtIndexPath***. Put a breakpoint at

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsFeedSectionHeaderCell") as! NewsFeedSectionHeaderCell
```

And check from the variable View (left to console where we see logs) or hover over this object to see whether this object is nil or not. It will be nil so it raising the exception.