# stepping may behave oddly;

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7

I am Developing an application with xcode 7.3.1 Swift language, My application crash on navigation with second view controller class's viewDidload method with below error 
" **was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.**"

```
   I have tried many solution which are available on google. can any one help me to solve this issue? this is not happened everytime. 2 or 3 time crashing with installation and than it works fine.
```

Note : This happened only with release mode not in debug mode.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a debugger message; in other words you cannot step through the code as the symbols might not line up with the compiled code.  I cannot see this as being related to your crashes, for which you will need to provide a symbolicated stacktrace and relevant code fragments to us.

Comment: okey I have some log with like this  <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable. just before this page so it may be the cause of crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Project Name' was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia)

Comment: @user3418619 Yeah possibly.  We need a symbolicated crash dump with the exception text/

Comment: @bienemann I have tried all the solution which are mention in your given llink Yes I have rename project multiple time but now I have new with frash one. with unique name but same error occurs