# AVAudioSession error: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

```
2017-02-24 14:56:44.280 PropertyManager[10172:5336578] 14:56:44.280 ERROR:    [0x1a0a24000] AVAudioSession.mm:692: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

2017-02-24 14:56:44.281 PropertyManager[10172:5336578] error === Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "(null)"
PropertyManager was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

Answer (score 20):

Your error log is very succinctly self-expressive:

```
Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session
```

It tells you the problem and also the solution.

Right now you're doing something like this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO
               withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                                             error:nil];
```

You should however, first stop the audio player instance and then set the activation status to Yes or No.

```
[yourAudioPlayer stop];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO
                   withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                                                 error:nil];
```

Refer to Apple Documentation to see values of [enum AudioSessionSetActiveOption](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessionsetactiveoptions?language=objc).

Also see: Apple Documentation on [setActive:withOptions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616627-setactive?language=objc) method

As for your second error

```
PropertyManager was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia).

Comment: [yourAudioPlayer stop] should be [yourAudioPlayer pause].

Comment: @TheiCoder Hmm why? It can be either of those, depending on the OP's needs.

Comment: I still get the error even after making sure the player has paused. I've even made it nil before trying to deactivate the session, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Jargen89 Put a breakpoint when you pause it, then inspect the element when you hit session deactivation. See if it is really paused or if some other line of code is making it resume.

Comment: @NSNoob, it's working now, but only after starting my machine and iphone back up the next morning. Thanks.

Comment: @ NSNoob could you also check this? tnx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910290/avaudiosession-plays-sound-on-receiver-or-mic-dont-tap

Comment: @NSNoob , is this still working from your end, pls testing this solution is giving same error on iOS 12+ . I will like to know if there is anything i can do as regards this, pls.

Comment: I still get the error even after pausing the player on iOS 14. So I called setActive: false method with a delay of 0.1 seconds after pausing my player, and there is no error log is printed.

Answer (score 1):

[@NSNoob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42433074/4833705) is 100% correct. The player (or something else) is still active.

More from [dani-mp](https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer/issues/139#issuecomment-393576428). He said:

> I'd say that pausing the player is not a synchronous operation, so we
> shouldn't be deactivating the session before knowing that the player
> has been paused ([see the response in this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/20435)).
>
> A solution for this problem could be that we listen to changes to
> timeControlStatus and deactivate the audio session once the player has
> really been paused.

The answer in the [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/20435) says

> This error indicates that something in your app is still using audio
> I/O at the time when the AVAudioSession setActive:NO is being called.
> It’s impossible to say which object without more information, but
> sometimes it’s the result of calling an asynchronous stop method on a
> player of some sort and not waiting for the notification that the
> player has stopped before deactivating the audio session.

Answer (score 0):

Make audio player to stop before making recording session false.. if u suppose to make audio player to be nil.. remove that line.. it works for me..

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution where I am using AVAudioEngine,AVAudioPlayerNode and using the concept of QUEUE. As the issue you mentioned occurs when interruption of audio session takes place.

Here is my implementation:

```
func playAudio(soundFile: String, alertTextmessage: String) {
    
    if let waveFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFile, withExtension: "wav") {
        do {
            // Create an AVAudioFile from the wave file URL
            let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: waveFileURL)
            
            // Calculate the duration of the audio file based on its length and format
            let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
            let audioFrameCount = UInt64(audioFile.length)
            let audioDuration = Double(audioFrameCount) / audioFormat.sampleRate
            
            // Create an AVAudioPlayerNode and attach it to the audio engine
            let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
            audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
            
            // Connect the player node to the main mixer node
            audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFormat)
            
            // Schedule the audio file for playback on the player node
            playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil)
            
            // Start the audio engine
            try audioEngine.start()
            
            // Start playback of the wave file
            playerNode.play()
            
            // After the wave file finishes playing, speak the text
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + audioDuration) {
                self.speakPhrase(phrase: alertTextmessage)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error playing wave file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Wav file not found.")
    }
}
```

here I am playing wav file leading with voice text audio.
You can access full File and uses on my Github
https://github.com/iAmita/MultipleAudioPlay.