# iOS: MapboxNavigationNative was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly;

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

We are facing  `MapboxNavigationNative was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly;` issue when we using navigation for about 10 to 20 mins. Kindly help us to overcome this issue.

After seeing many SO posts, I put all Optimization level to `none`

[image]

Comment: What problem is this causing? Debugging? Turning off optimization may affect performance in a bad way.

Comment: App getting crashed...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia Possible duplicate. Quick tip: Turn off optimization in `Apple Clang - Code generation` and in `Swift Compiler - Code Generation`. Also don't forget to clean project after disabling optimization

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue when calling `mapView.reloadStyle(self)` on background thread.
Investigate what method causes the crash and try calling it from main thread.