# How can I get the URL for BookmarkData in Swift when using it in a React Native native module?

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-native-module, native-module

Trying to call this method but url is not getting from bookmark data.

```
/// Returns an Asset pointing to a file on disk if it exists.
    func localAssetForStream(withName name: String) -> Asset? {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        print("KEY-VALUE 1 ",userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation())
        print("KEYS 2 ",UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)
        let val = userDefaults.value(forKey: name) as? Data;
        print("Value ",val);
        let val1 = userDefaults.value(forKey: name)
        print("Value1 ",val1);
        guard let localFileLocation = userDefaults.value(forKey: name) as? Data else { return nil }
        
        var asset: Asset?
        var bookmarkDataIsStale = false
        do {
            let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: localFileLocation,
                                    bookmarkDataIsStale: &bookmarkDataIsStale)

            if bookmarkDataIsStale {
                fatalError("Bookmark data is stale!")
            }
            
            let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
                        guard let asse = AssetListManager.sharedManager.assets.first(where: {$0.stream.name == name}) else { return nil }
            
            asset = Asset(stream: asse.stream, urlAsset: urlAsset)
            
            return asset
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to create URL from bookmark with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QwjE.jpg)

I am expecting it to work just like it is working in swift individual project and return local url for video.

Comment: I am able to find a solution for this issue by updating optimization level.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772573/project-name-was-compiled-with-optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-varia